# How to label or rename the data of all column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, mapping

I am struggling with the survey data. 
I have survey data which is baased on two file. 1 file is just the raw data and the other file contains the labeling of the data.

for example df_data look like:

```
User_id             Gender         Age
1000                  2             3
2000                  1             4
```

but there are about 25000 columns. And the second file data_label look like this:

```
    Age
     1            20-30
     2            31-40
     3            41-50
     4            51-60

   Gender        
     1             Male
     2             Female
```

So, i just want to map all the columns based on this df_label. I can do one by one using map function but the problem is that there are more than 25000 columns. Any help?

This is how label data look alike:
[image]

Comment: Is the format of the data_label file consistent? Is there always a single blank line between label mappings and name of mapping always matches the column head in df_data?

Comment: I just edited and attach the picture that how the data looks in real.